# Grabbed the action of a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uikit, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have code like this in my navigation bar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(self)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myButton;
```

What's the next step to grab when this is actually pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mad a mistake here by setting `@selector(self)`.

You need to put here the actual function you need to fire:

```
UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doSomeThing)];
```

And of course:

```
- (void) doSomeThing{

}
```

Comment: Ohh such a simple mistake, thx I'll mark it correct when its ready

Answer (score 2):

Do like this

```
   UIBarButtonItem *Button=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(myAction:)];
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=Button;


 - (void)myAction:(id)sender
    {
        //do ur actions 
    }
```